# How to download a CSV in Flutter Web keeping a cross-platform code?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am generating a csv file from a `List<List<dynamic>>` named `rows` as follows ...

```
String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
```

Then, If I'm on a mobile (Android or IOS) I send the file to an email and **if I'm on the web I download it to the device** using `AnchorElement` that is part of `import 'dart: html' as html` as follows:

```
    if (_prefs.platform == 'isWeb')
    {
      html.AnchorElement(href: "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,$csv")
        ..setAttribute("download", "report.csv")
        ..click();

    } else {

       //To write csv as a file in a path and send it using FlutterEmailSender

    }
```

It's working right on Web, but when I try to compile in Android or IOS an error appears:

> : Error: Not found: 'dart:html' import 'dart:html' as html;
> ^
>
> : Error: Method not found: 'AnchorElement'.
> html.AnchorElement(href: "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,$csv")

I think It's because dart:html is not supported by IOS and Android, so my questions are:

1. What other package / function can I use to download a CSV file on the Web, without generating compilation errors (cross-platform)?
2. As an alternative solution, can I use some command so that the Widget uses `dart:html` only if it is running in a web environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead:

```
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html hide Text;
```